# How to test Storm using Spock when emitting large output Tuples

Tags: java, groovy, apache-storm, spock

So I have the following test:

```
def "test execute(inputTuple) method emits an outputTuple containing a member ObjectType    
retrieved using the entity_id in inputTuple"() {
    given:
    Tuple inputTuple = Mock(Tuple);

    List<String> objectTypeIDsEmittedByPreviousBolt = new ArrayList<String>();
    objectTypeIDsEmittedByPreviousBolt.add("member");
    objectTypeIDsEmittedByPreviousBolt.add("1196");

    1 * inputTuple.getValues() >> objectTypeIDsEmittedByPreviousBolt;

    when:
    this.bolt.execute(inputTuple);

    then:
    1 * this.collector.emit(inputTuple, THE_OUTPUT_TUPLE);
    1 * this.collector.ack(inputTuple);
}
```

And I getting the following error which I don't understand. Is the inputTuple not matching or the outputTuple not matching?:

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * this.collector.emit( inputTuple, [['response':['status':'OK', ... 'member']]]])   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

1 * <OutputCollector>.emit(Mock for type 'Tuple' named 'inputTuple', [['response':['status':'OK', ...'member']]]])


    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.InteractionScope.verifyInteractions(InteractionScope.java:78)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.MockController.leaveScope(MockController.java:76)
    at member.bolt.CallConsoleAPIToGetAllObjectTypeInfoBoltTest.test execute(inputTuple) method emits an outputTuple containing a member ObjectType retrieved using the entity_id in inputTuple(CallConsoleAPIToGetAllObjectTypeInfoBoltTest.groovy:63)
```

Comment: Can You provide a minimal working example? Without it, it's difficult to say something that has any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how this test should probably be written (groovyConsole working example):

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class Test extends Specification {
    def "test execute(inputTuple) method emits an outputTuple containing a member ObjectType retrieved using the entity_id in inputTuple"() {
        given:    
        List<String> objectTypeIDsEmittedByPreviousBolt = new ArrayList<String>();
        objectTypeIDsEmittedByPreviousBolt.add("member");
        objectTypeIDsEmittedByPreviousBolt.add("1196");

        Tuple inputTuple = new Tuple(objectTypeIDsEmittedByPreviousBolt);

        Bolt bolt = new Bolt()
        Collector collector = GroovyMock(Collector)
        bolt.collector = collector

        when:
        bolt.execute(inputTuple);

        then:
        1 * collector.ack(inputTuple);
    }
}

class Bolt {
    Collector collector = new Collector()
    def execute(o) {
        collector.ack(o)
    }
}

class Collector {
    def ack(o) {
        println o
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting answer and glad You're satisfied with it. I'd like also to ask if You can award a started bounty?

Comment: sorry Opal. I thought it automatically awarded the answer. Thanks!