# How do I put Spock interactions on multiple lines?

Tags: groovy, spock

I have a really long interaction in Spock

```
reallyLongVariable.reallyLongMethod(argument, _, _, _, _, _) >> {n, a, builder, c, d, e -> builder.anotherLongMethod(SomeClass.staticInitializer(trackId));}
```

I would like to put it on multiple lines but get a `Groovyc: unexpected token >>` error message when I try to break it into multiple lines here.

```
reallyLongVariable.reallyLongMethod(argument, _, _, _, _, _) 
    >> {n, a, builder, c, d, e -> builder.anotherLongMethod(SomeClass.staticInitializer(trackId));}
```

Is there a way to break the statement into multiple lines before the `>>`?

Comment: Could You please provide a working groovyConsole example? Here's how to set it up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559983/how-to-test-storm-using-spock-when-emitting-large-output-tuples

Comment: Leave the >> on the previous line

Comment: and format your closure like a standard function block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Java, Groovy doesn't allow to break before an operator, but only after an operator. Another common solution is to break after the `->`.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I ended up breaking after the opening bracket.